# why doesn't my macro copy chart visual from duplicated sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace

i have a code duplicating a template sheet i created, except the chart data doesn't copy over. if i were to click "duplicate sheet manually", it appears no problem. the data source for the chart is on a separate sheet so i'm not sure where the disconnect is? this is the error message i get: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/l87DE.png)

code below. everything else works fine, just the visual of the pie chart does not appear on the new sheet

```
function createWeeklyReport() {
  // Calculate the date of the upcoming Friday
  var currentDate = new Date();
  var currentDay = currentDate.getDay(); // Sunday is 0, Monday is 1, ..., Saturday is 6
  var upcomingFriday = new Date();
  upcomingFriday.setDate(currentDate.getDate() + (5 - currentDay + 7) % 7);

  // Format the date for the sheet name and cell value (mm.dd.yy)
  var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(upcomingFriday, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), 'MM.dd.yy');
  var formattedDateForCell = Utilities.formatDate(upcomingFriday, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), 'MM/dd/yy');

  // Access the active spreadsheet
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  // Get the "temp" sheet
  var tempSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('temp');

  if (tempSheet) {
    // Create a copy of the "temp" sheet
    var newSheet = tempSheet.copyTo(spreadsheet);

    // Move the new sheet to the front
    spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(newSheet);
    spreadsheet.moveActiveSheet(1);

    // Rename the new sheet with the date of the upcoming Friday
    newSheet.setName('Weekly Report ' + formattedDate);

    // Set cell D5 to the date of the upcoming Friday in mm/dd/yy format
    newSheet.getRange('D5').setValue(formattedDateForCell);

  // Change the color of the new sheet to green
    newSheet.setTabColor("#228B22"); // Green color code

  } else {
    Logger.log('Sheet with the name "temp" not found.');
  }
}
```

Comment: When I tested your showing script to a sheet including a chart, it seems that the script works and the chart can be also shown in the copied sheet. So, I guess that in your situation, replicating your current issue might be useful for correctly understanding it. So, can you provide a sample Spreadsheet for correctly replicating your current issue?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1W6SCZzLp3X8dDrvbKlvstT_9hN2w5m-Rt5QXVHic6IM/edit?usp=sharing here is a link to the doc! the graph is pulled from the "source" sheet, and "temp" is what is duplicated to create the new weekly report

Comment: Thank you for replying and providing the sample Spreadsheet. Unfortunately, I couldn't open your sample Spreadsheet. I apologize for this.

Comment: sorry about that! i updated the permissions, i think you should be able to access now?

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your provided Spreadsheet, I could correctly replicate your issue. So, I proposed an answer by modifying your script. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your question and that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Modification points:

When I tested your showing script and your provided Spreadsheet, I confirmed that the chart in the copied sheet had no data ranges. When I saw your provided Spreadsheet, it seems that the data range of the chart is different sheet. When I tested your script with a sheet including the chart created by the data range of the same sheet, the script worked. I think that this might be the reason for your current issue. From this result, it seems that when the method "copyTo" of Class Sheet is used for a chart that the data range is a different sheet, the data range cannot be copied.

In your situation, how about the following modifications?

#### Modified script 1:

In this modification, after the sheet was copied, only the chart was replaced.

```js
function createWeeklyReport() {
  // Calculate the date of the upcoming Friday
  var currentDate = new Date();
  var currentDay = currentDate.getDay(); // Sunday is 0, Monday is 1, ..., Saturday is 6
  var upcomingFriday = new Date();
  upcomingFriday.setDate(currentDate.getDate() + (5 - currentDay + 7) % 7);

  // Format the date for the sheet name and cell value (mm.dd.yy)
  var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(upcomingFriday, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), 'MM.dd.yy');
  var formattedDateForCell = Utilities.formatDate(upcomingFriday, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), 'MM/dd/yy');

  // Access the active spreadsheet
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  // Get the "temp" sheet
  var tempSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('temp');

  if (tempSheet) {
    // Create a copy of the "temp" sheet
    var newSheet = tempSheet.copyTo(spreadsheet);

    // --- I modified the below script.
    newSheet.removeChart(newSheet.getCharts()[0]); // Added
    newSheet.insertChart(tempSheet.getCharts()[0]); // Added
    // ---

    // Move the new sheet to the front
    spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(newSheet);
    spreadsheet.moveActiveSheet(1);

    // Rename the new sheet with the date of the upcoming Friday
    newSheet.setName('Weekly Report ' + formattedDate);

    // Set cell D5 to the date of the upcoming Friday in mm/dd/yy format
    newSheet.getRange('D5').setValue(formattedDateForCell);

  // Change the color of the new sheet to green
    newSheet.setTabColor("#228B22"); // Green color code

  } else {
    Logger.log('Sheet with the name "temp" not found.');
  }
}
```

#### Modified script 2:

In this modification, Sheets API is used. Before you use this script, [please enable Sheets API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services).

```js
function createWeeklyReport() {
  // Calculate the date of the upcoming Friday
  var currentDate = new Date();
  var currentDay = currentDate.getDay(); // Sunday is 0, Monday is 1, ..., Saturday is 6
  var upcomingFriday = new Date();
  upcomingFriday.setDate(currentDate.getDate() + (5 - currentDay + 7) % 7);

  // Format the date for the sheet name and cell value (mm.dd.yy)
  var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(upcomingFriday, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), 'MM.dd.yy');
  var formattedDateForCell = Utilities.formatDate(upcomingFriday, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), 'MM/dd/yy');

  // Access the active spreadsheet
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  // Get the "temp" sheet
  var tempSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('temp');

  if (tempSheet) {

    // --- I modified the below script.
    // Create a copy of the "temp" sheet
    const newSheetName = 'Weekly Report ' + formattedDate;
    const requests = [{ duplicateSheet: { sourceSheetId: tempSheet.getSheetId(), insertSheetIndex: 0, newSheetName } }];
    Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({ requests }, spreadsheet.getId());
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    var newSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(newSheetName).activate();
    // ---

    // Set cell D5 to the date of the upcoming Friday in mm/dd/yy format
    newSheet.getRange('D5').setValue(formattedDateForCell);

  // Change the color of the new sheet to green
    newSheet.setTabColor("#228B22"); // Green color code

  } else {
    Logger.log('Sheet with the name "temp" not found.');
  }
}
```

- When these modified scripts are run to your provided Spreadsheet, I confirmed that "temp" sheet is correctly copied by including the chart.

#### Note:

- When a sheet is copied, when the same sheet name exists in the Spreadsheet, an error occurs. Please be careful about this.

#### References:

- [removeChart(chart)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#removechartchart)
- [insertChart(chart)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#insertchartchart)
- [Method: spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate)
- [DuplicateSheetRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#duplicatesheetrequest)

Comment: this is perfect THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!!! i super appreciate your help :

Comment: @Sydney About `this is perfect THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!!! i super appreciate your help`, welcome. Thank you for letting me know. I'm glad your issue was resolved. If your question was solved, please push an accept button. Other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question that can be solved. And I think that your issue and solution will be useful for them. If you don't find the button, feel free to tell me. https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer